# What are the default margins in browser print settings?

Tags: css, html, printing

Does anyone know how many inches are, by default, applied to the top and bottom margins of pages in web print? Specifically for IE and Chrome?  Is it half an inch maybe?

I'm asking because I'm writing some css code for adding headers and footers and have adopted a strategy that will use inches to set the heights of the divs on the page.

Answer (score 22):

If you want consistency across browsers, you probably want to set the margins consistently rather than rely on the default values. You can do this with @page CSS:

```
@page {
    margin-top: 0.75in;
    margin-bottom: 0.75in;
    margin-left: 0.75in;
    margin-right: 0.75in;    
}
```

Since printers themselves also have minimum margin sizes, and those vary by model and manufacturer, it's generally safest to not use a margin under 0.5inches.

Comment: Apologies to resurrect such an old post, but can I ask *how* you actually do this for Google Chrome? I've tried adding the above to the `target`, and running `chrome.exe @page...` from the terminal, but neither have been successful. Thanks :)

Comment: @SamT in the css print file, which you can specify with `media='print'` in your css link. This isn't for a general setting in Chrome.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. It's not such an important quesiton for me any more, but thanks anyway! :)

Comment: This doesn't work on Safari. You should specify that in your answer.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

Answer (score 20):

- Internet Explorer 0.75 inch.
- Chrome 0.4 inch.
- Firefox 0.5 inch

References

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-printing-problems-firefox

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/what-are-the-default-print-margins-for-ie-678-and/632198b6-d3b7-449a-853a-db8a745bf56e